# Is there some way I can use assign a value in MainPage and bind it in the child window

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, childwindow, staticresource

I've a Silverlight application wherein I've a MainPage in which I need to assign a variable Name in the childwindow and assign it without using the object of the child. I need to bind thise value to a textbox in the Childwindow through XAML. How can it be done?

So far what I've done is using a dependancy property in the childwindow:

```
    nameProp = DependencyProperty.Register("strName", typeof(string), typeof(TestWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnNameChange)));

    static TestWindow()
    {
        nameProp = DependencyProperty.Register("strName", typeof(string), typeof(TestWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnNameChange)));
    }

    private static void OnNameChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        d.SetValue(nameProp, e.NewValue);
    }

    public string strName
    { 
        get {
        return (string)GetValue(nameProp);
        }

        set {
            SetValue(nameProp, value);
        }
    }
```

and in TestWindow XAML i try to bind it:

```
       <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=strName}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="126,84,0,0" Name="txtName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

How can I set the value for this dp from MainPage. Or is there any better alternative?

Comment: Probably this is that what you're looking for: [Creating a Silverlight DataContext Proxy to Simplify Data Binding in Nested Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

One way will be:

1. Make those variables public properties of your MainPage.
2. Assign the mainPage to be your child window DataContext.
3. Bind to those properties via XAML in your childWindow.

Comment: @Micheal: I've changed the question. I hope you would get a better understanding of my need.

Answer (score 0):

i am hoping that  this will helps you....what you are trying to achieve....

ChildWindow Xaml file:

```
     <controls:ChildWindow x:Class="ParentToChildWindow.ChildWindowControl"

           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

           xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"

           Width="400" Height="300"

           Title="Pass Data from Parent to ChildWindow">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="2">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RowDefinition />

            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical">

            <TextBlock x:Name="txtValue" />

            <TextBlock x:Name="txtName"/>

        </StackPanel>

        <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" Click="CancelButton_Click" Width="75"

                Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,12,0,0" Grid.Row="1" />

        <Button x:Name="OKButton" Content="OK" Click="OKButton_Click" Width="75" Height="23"

                HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,12,79,0" Grid.Row="1" />

    </Grid>

</controls:ChildWindow>
```

ChildWindow CS file:

```
namespace ParentToChildWindow    
{

    using System.Windows;   
    using System.Windows.Controls;

    public partial class ChildWindowControl : ChildWindow    
    {

        public int Value { get; set; }    
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ChildWindowControl()    
        {   
            InitializeComponent();

        }    
        private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    
        {

            this.txtValue.Text = this.Value.ToString();    
            this.txtName.Text = this.Name;    
        }
        private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    
        {
                this.DialogResult = false;

        }

    }

}
```

Parent CS File: I have added a button to parent XAML and added a click event

```
 private void HandleButtonClickEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    
 {

   ChildWindowControl childControl = new ChildWindowControl();    
   childControl.Value = 10;
   childControl.Name = "Data From Parent XAML to ChildWindow";    
   childControl.Show();

 }
```

Pass the value in the constructor of theChildWindow

For this the place where we create the new instance of ChildWindow, we need to pass the required values to the Constructor. But remember, there must be a matching constructor already present in the ChildWindow control.

```
public ChildWindowControl(int value, string name)    
{

   InitializeComponent();    
   this.Value = value;    
   this.Name = name;

 }
```

That is all that is required to pass the data from Parent XAML to ChildWindow

Comment: is it possible for me to access the constructor parameters from xaml?